# Mis migragraciones no se cargan en Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

Estoy trabajando con *Django*, al desplegar en *Heroku*. **Mis tablas no se cargan** solo las de *Django*, ***no** detecta cambios en las **migraciones***.

Antes que nada hago migraciones locales y usando comando de *Heroku*:

```py
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations


heroku run python manage.py migrate
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
```

Cualquiera de ellas me dice **no hay cambios**:

> Operations to perform:
> Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, **dashboard**, sessions
> Running migrations:
> **No migrations to apply.**

Ya hice lo que menciona [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330432/django-makemigrations-and-migrate-on-heroku-server-dont-create-tables) pero igual no detecta mis tablas

```py
heroku run bash
```

Warning: heroku update available from 7.42.0 to 7.42.1.

> Running bash on ⬢ miappheroku... up, run.4645 (Free)
>
> > $ python manage.py migrate
> > Operations to perform:
> > Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, dashboard, sessions
> > Running migrations:
> > No migrations to apply.
> > $ python manage.py makemigrations dashboard
> > No changes detected in app 'dashboard'

Mi **DB** esta hecha en *PostgreSQL*, esta es la **config** que uso usando la librería [dj-database-url/](https://pypi.org/project/dj-database-url/) en este [proyecto](https://github.com/jacobian/dj-database-url) hay una documentación mas extensa:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://abcdef...')
}
```

Y estas son las **variables** que se crean en mi **app** de *Heroku*:

[image: config_var_Heroku]

Por si falta alguna, puede ser el caso.

Y mi archivo `requirements.txt`:

```
asgiref==3.2.7
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.7
django-filter==2.3.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
djangorestframework==3.11.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
importlib-metadata==1.6.1
psycopg2==2.8.5
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
python-decouple==3.3
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
whitenoise==5.1.0
zipp==3.1.0
```

De antemano gracias cualquier idea/sugerencia.

**OJO** primero subi mis migraciones junto con el codigo pero habian **cambios** asi que luego las genere pero dio los mismo, no **reconoce** mis tablas

Comment: No se mucho sobre desplieges, pero primero debe ser `makemigratios` (solo se **crean** las migraciones) y después `migrate` (que seria **aplicar** las migraciones). Y según leí la documentación de Heroku, debes crear las tablas así: `heroku run python manage.py migrate`, no así: `python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: este es un error que aveces pasa, lo solucione con python manage.py makemigrations en el aplicativo y lo subi a heroku para despues heroku run python manage.py migrate ya crear las tablas